# Creating a Dummy Variable

Tags: r

I am working on birthweight data with categories cigs smoked per day, male, white.

I am trying to create dummy variable for nonsmoker which I used `nonsmoker<-ifelse(data$cig==0,1,0)`, but for light smokers, which would be between 1-5 cigarettes per day, I'm not sure on how to set a series.

I thought maybe `light smoker<-ifelse(data$cigs==1-5,1,0)` would work, but guess not.

Comment: You are probably looking for `cut`. Have a read of `?cut` and search this on SO within the R tag. R automatically will create dummies if you set up a proper factor variable. `cut` is probably the best way to go as you can also add informative names to the levels. As a side note, please do not mention or tag rstudio unless you have a question with rstudio itself. R and rstudio are independent software applications.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a boolean to select values greater than 1 and less than 5. So something like:

`smoker<-ifelse((data$cigs>=1) & (data$cigs<=5),1,0)`

You could also use the `cut` method to create a factor, the levels of which you could then rename:

```
cig <- 0:10  # your original data
smoker <- cut(cig , c(-1, 0, 5, 10))
levels(smoker) <- c("0", "1-5", "6-10")  # rename the levels
```

which will then give you a factor that looks like this:

```
> smoker
 [1] 0    1-5  1-5  1-5  1-5  1-5  6-10 6-10 6-10 6-10 6-10
```

You can set your cut boundaries (i.e. is the range inclusive/exclusive of the end points?) by playing with the `include.lowest` and `right` arguments of the `cut` method

Comment: The OP is really looking for `cut`. With the method you suggest, he'd have to write a line for each level of the variable of interest and also add that variable to the data.frame. This can easily be collapsed into a single line using `cut`. This is not only a single line of code, but also will be efficiently interpreted by `lm`, `glm` or the other modeling functions that use the formula interface. I won't downvote your answer, but have to disagree with this method.

Comment: Well, I tried to provide an answer within the specific constraints of his problem (i.e., why does the current code not work). However, I know that `cut` is more ideal

Comment: It is better to supply a complete answer rather than simply fulfill the minimal need. This will reduce the number of follow up questions as well as help future readers of the post avoid the same mistakes.

Comment: That's great. Even better, include the labels argument. Then you'd have `smoker <- cut(cig , breaks=c(-1, 0, 5, 10), labels=c("0", "1-5", "6-10"))` with the same result or a perhaps more descriptive `smoker <- cut(cig , breaks=c(-1, 0, 5, 10), labels=c("non-smoker", "light-smoker", "mega-smoker"))`.